# How do I get all the children objects of the children objects of an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Sorry for the confusing title, I wasn't sure how to word that. But I have the `User` class which has many `projects`. And the `Project` class has many `wbs_items`. So how do I get all the `wbs_items` that belong to all the `projects`that belong to a single user?

Ideally I would do:

```
current_user.projects.wbs_items
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, post your user, project and wbs models.

Comment: Do you mean grandchildren objects?

Comment: I did not realize that was a thing but yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding this line to my model:

```
has_many :wbs_items, :through => :projects
```

Then I could get all the `wbs_items` by doing:

```
current_user.wbs_items
```

Comment: Yes that's the most common pattern in Rails. If you run that in the console it should spit out the SQL queries required to fetch the "gradchildren" objects: first it runs a query to get all `project_ids` for this `user`, then it runs a second query to get all `wbs_items` attached to any of those `project_ids`.

Answer (score 1):

```
# User model
has_many :projects
has_many :wbs_items, through: :projects

# this will return all wbs_items of the current user
current_user.wbs_items
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, I would think your approach could look like the following:

1. Create hash for project/wbs_items relations: Projects => [array_of_wbs_items]
2. Iterate over Users and assign wbs_items based on looking up the Project in the project/wbs_items hash